# How to determine if the ethernet frame is an IPv4 packet?

Tags: network-programming, ethernet, dpdk

I use pcap_pmd in a DPDK application, and it does not set the `packet_type` field automatically. How can I determine the correct packet type after the packet is received from the interface?

**edit**:
The ethernet header structure:

```
/**
 * Ethernet header: Contains the destination address, source address
 * and frame type.
 */
struct ether_hdr {
    struct ether_addr d_addr; /**< Destination address. */
    struct ether_addr s_addr; /**< Source address. */
    uint16_t ether_type;      /**< Frame type. */
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

does not give a clue on where to search for the L3 protocol identifier.

Comment: You are asking two different question in the title and the question body. Are you asking about how to determine if a package is an IPv4 packet, or how to *make* a packet an IPv4 packet?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , I am sorry for confusion, by 'get it done' I meant fulfill the `packet_type` with the correct value, whether it is IPv4, IPv6, ARP or any other protocol, carried by this packet. I reformulated the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging just a bit deeper into the `rte_ether.h` header gave the answer: `ether_hdr::ether_type` is the desired next protocol id, it can have one of the following values:

```
/* Ethernet frame types */
#define ETHER_TYPE_IPv4 0x0800 /**< IPv4 Protocol. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_IPv6 0x86DD /**< IPv6 Protocol. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_ARP  0x0806 /**< Arp Protocol. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_RARP 0x8035 /**< Reverse Arp Protocol. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_VLAN 0x8100 /**< IEEE 802.1Q VLAN tagging. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_1588 0x88F7 /**< IEEE 802.1AS 1588 Precise Time Protocol. */
#define ETHER_TYPE_SLOW 0x8809 /**< Slow protocols (LACP and Marker). */
#define ETHER_TYPE_TEB  0x6558 /**< Transparent Ethernet Bridging. */
```

Comment: You should accept your answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: OK, remember to accept this answer. I wouldn't be able to remind you for this answer after 2 days, :)